# Generate Public Key

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, cryptography, public-key

I use the command:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xac844bd1107761fec3abe2f55bf739f0e7cc6dd1cd169a60176bfb22
9826b5a8")
```

Where the brackets contain the hash of the successful transaction.
This is what I get:

```
{
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xcf03e41ee1116bed4f1acf8a2209b4d37d755988",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 18000000000,
  hash: "0xac844bd1107761fec3abe2f55bf739f0e7cc6dd1cd169a60176bfb229826b5a8",
  input: "0x165c4a16000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006",
  nonce: 28,
  r: "0x4f674ff118c840d032fb3cba8ba0f9cdaed1f73be54f08b487fe1204b5bab809",
  s: "0x736f214a50ad1b417380e2c0aee273459f78fac0bd37deb59b4e7c112736acee",
  to: "0x2608273b77ef3964ceb1fb488d4b95b30258d091",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0xf09",
  value: 0
}
```

Can I make use of any of the above values to generate the Public Key of my transaction?

Comment: A transaction does not have a public key. Are you referring to the hash of the transaction?

Comment: Yes. I mean the hash of the transaction

Comment: You already have the public transaction.

Comment: Where do I have the public key?

Comment: I feel like we're going in circles. Have you tried recursion? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure, you may recover public key from your transaction using [ABDK Toolkit](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#recover-address).  For this you need your transaction in raw hexadecimal format.  You may again use [ABDK Toolkit](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#transaction) to convert transaction into this format.

Your particular transaction in raw format looks like this:

```
0xf8ac1c850430e2340083015f90942608273b77ef3964ceb1fb488d4b95b30258
  d09180b844165c4a160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000000006820f09a04f674ff118c840d032fb3cba8ba0f9cdaed1f7
  3be54f08b487fe1204b5bab809a0736f214a50ad1b417380e2c0aee273459f78
  fac0bd37deb59b4e7c112736acee
```

And public key (uncompressed) looks like this:

```
0x0469eb01db87542d8ba782c8d80bbbe6ac0d474e91a89e9cee71570397acc3b1
  2089bd327411cf25940df653eb86a4de63740edf760ef6448a74e905668c9b57
  d0
```